# Spring boot devtools and dependent spring projects

Tags: spring-boot, devtools

I have a large-scale Spring Boot application which is composed of several projects, with dependencies between projects. Two of the projects are "web applications" and can be run in the usual manner. Both include Spring's devtools for restart/live reload capabilities. Everything builds/runs fine, with the exception of the devtools features.

The problem we're having is that once one of the applications is started, the ENTIRE application directory becomes part of the reload trigger - resources, templates, CSS, gradle.build ... touching ANY file from the root of the sub-project down triggers a reload. This makes front-end development tedious, to say the least.

One of the projects, call it Project1, has a SpringBoot app that is located in project1/app directory. It has dependencies to project1/core and another project called "commons."

At the start of the console output, these lines appear:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, ...]
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading :
file:/C:/.../project1/app/bin/, 
file:/C:/.../project1/core/bin/,
file:/C:/.../commons/bin/,
file:/C:/.../project1/app/]
```

It appears to be this last entry that causes the entire project1/app directory to be scanned for restart on any change.

A "standard" starter project with devtools shows this for the same line:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/.../auto-restart/bin/]
```

If I add a dependency to one of the other projects, it shows up like this:

```
DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/C:/.../auto-restart/bin/, file:/C:/.../commons/bin/]
```

which looks right to me - no top-level folder included.

One last note: using Eclipse, if the one of the "misbehaving" projects is running, the "Trigger devtools restart" icon on the console header does not work. It does work correctly for the small sample project.

I have not been able to find any information on how the ChangeableUrls list is built, or why it might pick up the app root directory in addition to /bin. Attempting to change the include or exclude parameters in application.properties has no affect - the entire directory is still scanned for changes.

Interestingly, including spring.devtools.restart.trigger-file property DOES stop scanning everything ... but it defeats the purpose for back-end development.

Answer (score 0):

As per the question my best possible guess would be to check the following configuration either in application.property or application.yml (based on your project setup)

If you using application.yml then look for : -

```
spring:
  devtools:
    restart:
     additional-paths:
        - .
```

If you using application.properties then look for : -

```
spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths = .
```

Try to search for this configuration in your spring boot project and if you find such configuration then please try disable/comment the configuration and then test your application.

With configuration "spring.devtools.restart.additional-paths = ." spring boot allows you to restart the whole application with slight change in the file.

Here is article which you can refer for more details : - [SpringBoot Devtools](https://jhooq.com/spring-boot-devtools/)